# VNC server on Arch with i3 and VNC viewer on Win 7

Tags: arch-linux, windows, vnc, i3

I have a laptop with `Arch` and `i3` installed and a desktop with `Win 7` installed.

My goal is to run a VNC server on the laptop and connect to it from my `Win 7` desktop via VNC viewer and be able to use my `i3config` that I have setup on the laptop itself.

I have `tigervnc` installed on the laptop and `TightVNC` installed on my desktop. I am able to start a `vncserver` and then connect to it from the `vncviewer`, but here's the tricky part...

I can't get `i3` to work properly on my desktop. Once I am connected to the server it displays 4 `xterm` instances without any proper layout (scattered accross the screen in no order). Do I have to export my `i3config` somehow to the `vncviewer`?

Unfortunately I am at work at the moment so I can't paste my `.xstartup` but I can do that once I get home.

Have anyone of you gotten `VNC` to properly work with `i3`? If so, how?

**Just to clarify**: I don't have any issues with connecting to the server, I just don't get the wm (in this case `i3`) to work.

**TLDR; How do I get `i3` to work with a `Windows 7` client using `VNCviewer`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another solution to this.

I used `x0vncserver` instead (which is included in the `tigervnc` package).

You can start the server via `x0vncserver -display :0 -passwordfile ~/.vnc/passwd`.